# SQL Server CE 3.5 sp2 PDA application hangs on SqlCeConnection.Close method

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I have developed an application using Visual Studio 2008 on .NET CE 3.5 framework. In backend I am using a SQL Server CE 3.5 sp2 database.

This application is running on Motorola PDA devices.

**Problem:**

Whenever `SqlCeConnection.Close` method is called, the application hangs and I need to forcefully crash the application and restart it.

Has anyone come across this issue before and found any solution?

Regards,
Brijen

Comment: You connection string and exact SQL CE version/build/file version - is your database located on a SD card?

Comment: Yes my sql ce database is on SD card. I have also tried it to locate on device memory also but still it gives issue.

Comment: Thanks - Still awaiting connection string and exact version information!

Comment: **Connection string**: Data Source=\Storage Card\StockCountingDB\MySQLDB.sdf;Password=xyz

Comment: **system.data.sqlserverce.dll**: File version- 3.5.8109.0, Product version: 3.5.8109.0